# How to select rows after x amount of rows in mysql?

Tags: mysql

Suppose I have:

`````````````````````````````````````
 __________________________________
| ID |   NAME   |       ITEM        |
-----------------------------------
| 2 |   John   |        vlc        |
````````````````````````````````````
| 3 |   mike   |        vlc        |
````````````````````````````````````
| 4 |   ali    |        vlc        |
````````````````````````````````````
| 5 |   Insan  |        vlc        |
````````````````````````````````````
| 6 |   Hawai  |        vlc        |
````````````````````````````````````
| 7 |   Jack   |        vlc        |
````````````````````````````````````
| 8 |   Chan   |        vlc        |
````````````````````````````````````
`````````````````````````````````````

Now I have a query which is:

```
SELECT NAME FROM table WHERE ITEM='vlc' LIMIT 2
```

As you might know this selects first and seconds row as I have limited it to select up to two rows so the result would be `John` and `Mike`.

**Question:**

What I want is to Select 2 rows after two first rows, say `ali` and `Insan`.
Such as:

```
SELECT NAME FROM table WHERE ITEM='vlc' LIMIT 2 but after 2 first rows
```

or

```
SELECT NAME FROM table WHERE ITEM='vlc' LIMIT 2 but after 5 first rows
```

Thanks for everything :)

Comment: Try with `limit 2,2` (for second 2), `limit 4,2` (for third 2)

Comment: Dont assume the query SELECT NAME FROM table WHERE ITEM='vlc' LIMIT 2 selects John and Mike without a ORDER BY id ASC

Comment: @RaymondNijland i dont think its required

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `OFFSET`

```
SELECT NAME FROM table WHERE ITEM='vlc' LIMIT 2 OFFSET 5
```

You can use short query without `OFFSET` along with `LIMIT` using comma as follows

`SELECT NAME FROM table WHERE ITEM='vlc' LIMIT 5,2`

**Notice that,in the second method the OFFSET value comes first and then the LIMIT value**

Comment: The query should have ORDER BY id ASC

Comment: @RaymondNijland Why is it required when records are sorted in ascending order by default

Comment: MySQL can return records in any order when there no ORDER BY.. dont trust the "default" order without a ORDER BY

Answer (score 1):

You can also use

```
SELECT NAME FROM table WHERE ITEM='vlc' LIMIT 2, 2
```

Answer (score 0):

In mysql you can use the LIMIT with OFFSET

```
SELECT NAME FROM table WHERE ITEM='vlc' LIMIT 2 OFFSET 2
```

This will return 2 values starting with the third value